# Hingejoint/point jumps from 2d character to camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I have this object that respawns and that has a hinge point to make it collide and rotate around a point, but it would seem my hinges, after and before picking them up causes them to snap to the camera, not allowing me to move the object anymore. Can I get help on this?

```
public class DragAndDropHinge : MonoBehaviour
{
    //This script is used to pick up 2d rigid bodies and spin them/throw them
    public Rigidbody2D rb;

    GameObject HingePoint;
    HingeJoint2D hinge;

    Vector2 velocity;
    Vector2 lastPosition;
    Vector2 objPosition;

    bool move = false;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        //Finds a GameObject with the name "HingePoint"
        HingePoint = GameObject.Find("HingePoint");
    }

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        //Saves the mouse position to screen coordinates
        Vector2 mousePosition = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);
        HingePoint.transform.position = new Vector3(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition).x, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition).y, HingePoint.transform.position.z);
        //Saves the HingeJoint2D component to variable that we can use
        hinge = HingePoint.GetComponent(typeof(HingeJoint2D)) as HingeJoint2D;
        //A Boolean that indicates we can start calculating movement
        move = true;
        //Reenables the hinge which is likely disabled after OnMouseUp is used
        hinge.enabled = true;
        //Assigns whatever rigid body we have clicked on to our hinge
        hinge.connectedBody = rb;
        //Prevents the hinge from adjusting the anchorpoint during fixed update, this well be set to true in OnMouseUp
        hinge.autoConfigureConnectedAnchor = false;

    }
    private void Update()
    {
        HingePoint.transform.position = rb.position;
        HingePoint.transform.rotation = rb.transform.rotation;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (move == true)
        {
            //Saves the mouse position to screen coordinates
            Vector2 mousePosition = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);
            HingePoint.transform.position = new Vector3(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition).x, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition).y, HingePoint.transform.position.z);

            //-----Continuously calculates the velocity to apply to the object after it has been thrown-----
            //Takes the current object postition to use for the velocity calculation
            objPosition = transform.position;
            //Calculates velocity
            velocity = (objPosition - lastPosition) / (Time.fixedDeltaTime);
            //Saves the current position for use in the next velocity calculation
            lastPosition = transform.position;

        }
    }

    private void OnMouseUp()
    {
        //Removes the hinges influence from the rigidbody
        hinge.connectedBody = null;
        //Allows the Anchor point to be moved for when we click on a new rigid body
        hinge.autoConfigureConnectedAnchor = true;
        //Disables the rigid body
        hinge.enabled = false;
        //Stops the calculations in FixedUpdate
        move = false;
        //Combines the velocity from the mouse with the velocity from the hinge and applies it to the desired rigid body
        rb.velocity = rb.velocity + velocity;
    }
}
```

I am expecting it to stay on the object and not snap off of it and that when more of that object is spawn, that each of them hold their hingepoints individually and not be disabled

Comment: I am a bit confused .. they all use the very same `HingePoint` object .. and you are always updating it to have the same position as your rigidbody .. what exactly are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why the hingepoint's ancor keeps snapping to the middle of the camera its. Strange. Could it be of autoconfig?